# Are there any good techniques for reducing or smoothing stutter after a longer frame?

Tags: opengl, sprites, monogame, sdl2

I've been using SDL2 with OpenGL to play around with some very basic game engine development. I'm running everything on a newer laptop with Linux and Intel integrated graphics.

Regardless of whether I have VSync on or off, occasionally a call to SDL_GL_SwapWindow (glxSwapBuffers under the hood) will take ~22-33ms which causes a noticeable stutter in any moving sprites. These long frames happen even if the game loop contains nothing but a call to glClear followed by SDL_GL_SwapWindow, so I'm assuming this is just due to everything running on a relatively underpowered system (and I don't see the long frames or stutter on my desktop with dedicated graphics).

I would have given up here and left it at the laptop not being cut out for OpenGL, but when I look at some indie games running on the same laptop, I'm unable to notice any of these stutter effects leading me to believe there may be a way to eliminate them (or that I'm doing something wrong). A few of the indie games were built with Monogame and at least one is also using SDL2 and OpenGL. I used apitrace to look at the OpenGL calls being made by these games and nothing looks very different from what I'm doing.

I then spun up a very basic Monogame project on my own machine, but still experienced the long frames and sprite stutter. I've tried different variations of fixed and variable game loops / timesteps as well as deltatime averaging to try to smooth over longer frames, but I still have a noticeable stutter.

Is there anything else I can do to eliminate the stutter or the long frames?